# Cefsharp chromium browser throws error on Windows 2012 R2

Tags: c#, .net, cefsharp

In my windows application I'm using Cefsharp ChromiumWebBrowser control. I can successfully load a URL if I run the application on Windows 10 OS but with same set of dll's copied onto Windows 2012 R2 virtual machine, application throws "Could not load file or assembly 'CefSharp.Core.Runtime.dll' or one of its dependencies. The specified module could not be found." error.

I have already made sure all related dll's are available in the application folder and .NET framework on my Windows 10 PC and on 2012 R2 VM are same.

Did anyone experience this error, does Cefsharp ChromiumWebBrowser work on 2012 R2 OS? any help is appreciated.

Comment: Does the server have a minimum of Microsoft  Visual c++ 2019 installed? https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/blob/cefsharp/101/NuGet/Readme.txt#L26

Comment: Installing C++ 2019 fixed the issue. Thanks.