# Cefsharp chromium browser v121 throws error on Windows 2012 R2

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, cefsharp, windows-server-2012-r2

In my windows application I'm using Cefsharp ChromiumWebBrowser control version 121. I can successfully load a URL if I run the application on Windows 10 OS but with same set of dll's copied onto Windows 2012 R2 virtual machine, application throws "Could not load file or assembly 'CefSharp.Core.Runtime.dll' or one of its dependencies. The specified module could not be found." error.
As Program works fine on Win 10 x64, so Cef initialization seems correct.

this is similar to post: [Cefsharp chromium browser throws error on Windows 2012 R2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72278700/cefsharp-chromium-browser-throws-error-on-windows-2012-r2?newreg=57eccfed5b004b5f9a467a372bed7fca)

i downloaded combined 2015-2022 VC++ runtime and installed x64 version form https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/cpp/windows/latest-supported-vc-redist?view=msvc-170 .
i continue to get the same error!!
anyone has faced this ? Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Chrome 109 is the last version of Chrome that will support Windows 7, Windows 8/8.1, Windows Server 2012, and Windows Server 2012 R2.  Chrome 110 (tentatively scheduled for release on February 7th, 2023) is the first version of Chrome that requires Windows 10 or later.

`M109` is the last version to support running on `2012R2`. Newer versions won't run on `2012R2`

Official `Chorme` announcement is at [Sunsetting support for Windows 7 / 8/8.1 and Windows Server 2012 and 2012 R2 in early 2023](https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/185534985/sunsetting-support-for-windows-7-8-1-in-early-2023?hl=en)

Comment: Thanks amaitland, downgrading to 109 version to 2012R2 worked